# How to produce "SpatialPixelsDataFrame" from stacked RasterLayer?

Tags: raster, r, raster-conversion

How to produce "SpatialPixelsDataFrame" from staccked RasterLayer ?

I have a stacked rasterlayer and I want to convert them to SpatialPixelsDataFrame.

RasterLayer information is

```
> RAD.all[[1]]
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 180, 240, 43200  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.01, 0.01  (x, y)
extent      : -123.305, -120.905, 36.705, 38.505  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : C:\Users\Michael\Documents\1998bil\1998ASC5min_ppt_spas1214_0001_19980202_0810_UTC.asc.bil 
names       : X1998ASC5min_ppt_spas1214_0001_19980202_0810_UTC.asc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two nice packages in (Macro)Ecology that have a workaround for what you want to do:

```
library(raster)
library(SDMTools)
library(adehabitat)

r <- raster("yourFile.tif") # Get a link to a raster
rAsc <- asc.from.raster(r) # Function from SDMTools to convert to asc format
b <- asc2spixdf(rAsc) # Function from adehabitat to convert to SpatialPixelDataFrame
class(b) # See if it worked
>[1] "SpatialPixelsDataFrame"
>attr(,"package")
>[1] "sp"
```

Then just apply this in a loop or via StackApply and a custom function to your stacked object.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Yes, I can see                                          > class(b)
[1] "SpatialPixelsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
>

Comment: Very inefficient approach. mdsummer's suggestion is the correct answer.

Answer (score 13):

Coercion methods are included in the `raster` package:

```
as(RAD.all, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")
```

Comment: It works very well. Thanks.                             > AA <- as(RAD.all, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")
> class(AA)
[1] "SpatialPixelsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"