# Large raster stack to SpatialPixelsDataFrame runtime

Tags: raster, r

I want to create a SpatialPixelDataFrame from a large raster stack (49 layers of 29000 x 23000 pixels each) using the code from [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111511/how-to-produce-spatialpixelsdataframe-from-stacked-rasterlayer) post.

```
sppix <- st_as_sf(as(raster_stack, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame"))
```

When trying to convert the entire raster stack, R crashes, displaying

```
Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)
```

Even for a small subset (i.e. 4 layers & 10% of original area) of the raster stack the runtime is enormous.

Any suggestions for how to proceed with large raster stacks?

> sessionInfo()
> R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
> Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.6

Comment: How big is your "big"? How many rows/cols as well as layers? Is it the `as` conversion or the `st_as_sf` conversion that's bloating it? Why convert to an `sp` class and then to an `sf` class when there's probably ways of doing it in one go? Why use the `raster` package when `terra` can do this and probably faster?

Comment: @Spacedman I have added the dimensions of the raster stack in the original post (29000 x 23000 pixels, 49 layers). The final result should be of class `SpatialPixelsDataFrame`. I assume the `st_as_sf` is thus redundant. it is the `as` function that inflates the computational time. How could I use `terra` to implement a fast conversion?

Comment: The `st_as_sf` converts it to a different data structure altogether. If you don't need an `sf` object, then you don't need that call. As to the size, this is going to have 29,000x23,000x49 = 32 billion rows, so you'll need something over 100Gb of RAM just to store it. Trying to then do anything with it will be painfully slow. You may want to rethink your processing...

Comment: Maybe ignore what I said about `terra`, if you really need a SpatialPixelsDataFrame then that package won't help you, but it might be faster for converting its raster data to data frame format. Won't help much with the size though.

Comment: Why do you want to create a SpatialPixelsDataFrame? I think you are adding an extra step. [check this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/351689/converting-raster-layer-to-simple-feature-in-r)

Comment: @Spacedman (and @aldo_tapia) you are right, this is going to be very slow processing. The reason why I tried to convert the data structure is to adopt to the workflow for the ranger package in R that uses randomforest models to predict over large areas such as in [this](https://github.com/thengl/GeoMLA/blob/master/RF_vs_kriging/R/RF_uncertainty_maps.R) tutorial.